# Can GZWeb play a gazebo log file?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If we generate a log file using gzserver, can it be replayed in gzweb?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13200/can-gzweb-play-a-gazebo-log-file?/) by [srees](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2391/srees/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

GzWeb is just a visualization tool, it needs a `gzserver` running in the background.

So you can replay a log on `gzserver` just like you normally would, and visualize that using GzWeb.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-10-04**:
FYI, we're adding log playback **control** to GzWeb 2.0, see the pull request: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gzweb/pull-requests/101